# Lights Out C# Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

We have the Lights out Game to program

```
        Button[,] lights = new Button[5,5];

            for (int i = 0; i < lights.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lights.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    lights[i, j] = new Button();
                    lights[i, j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
                    lights[i, j].Click += (sender, args) => light_OnOff(lights[i,j], i, j);
                    lights[i, j].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    lightPanel.Controls.Add(lights[i, j]);

                    MessageBox.Show("I:"+Convert.ToString(i) + "J:" +Convert.ToString(j));
                }
            }
        }

        public void light_OnOff(object sender, int i, int j)
        {
            if(lights[i, j].BackColor == Color.Yellow)
            {
                lights[i, j].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having right now is that it says its out of `Array` Range (the index) but I don't know why. Maybe you could help me.

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown? Anyway you should easily get the issue when using a debugger and inspect what `i` and `j` are.

Comment: the exception is shown as soon as i click the "light Button" which should be at starting the "light_OnOff" Method

Comment: Did you try debugging the method?

Comment: I tried debugging it but Visual Studio 2015 crashed plus i found the error in Line 28 which is in my project the 
lights[i, j].Click += (sender, args) => light_OnOff(lights[i,j], i, j);

Comment: Are you trying to get, which button is clicked?

Comment: Yes i tried that and as soon as i used "this.BackColor" it changed the Color of the Form

Comment: As an aside you can simplify your code a bit by using the `sender`-object which actually *points* to the object being clicked. Thus you won´t need a global `lights`-variable and can ommit the indexes from that particular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating event with your way, set button's name to seperate them from each other.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lights.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lights.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                lights[i, j] = new Button();
                lights[i, j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
                lights[i, j].Name = "button" + i.ToString() + j.ToString(); // set name like this
                lights[i, j].Click += autoGeneratedEventName_Click; //after "+=" hit tab twice visual studio will create event auto;
                lights[i,j].Location = new Point(40 + (j*70), 20 + (i * 70));
                lights[i, j].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(lights[i, j]);

                //MessageBox.Show("I:" + Convert.ToString(i) + "J:" + Convert.ToString(j));
            }
        }
```

And at the event, sender will solve the problem, you don't need to send the array's indexes to event. (also you can find the indexes from buttons last 2 name)

```
private void autoGeneratedEventName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = sender as Button; //Clicked object is a Button
            if (b.BackColor == Color.Yellow) 
            {
                b.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            label1.Text = b.Name;
        }
```

Result;

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: Yeah it helped thanks a lot, now i just need to figure out how to "deactivate" a cross at once.

Comment: Just add else statement on Event, it is not a big deal. @RonAmme

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a so called "closure" in your code.

```
lights[i, j].Click += (sender, args) => light_OnOff(lights[i,j], i, j);
```

The variables i & j aren't copied by the lamdba expression, but handled as references, which still exist after these loops ended. So when a click event is triggered, it uses the latest values of i & j (5), which results in an out of array range exception.

To get the expected behaviour, you can copy i & j to local variables, like this:

```
int e = i; int f = j; 
lights[i, j].Click += (sender, args) => light_OnOff(lights, e, f);
```

Read this for more information: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx